# Custom attribute declaration for methods

Tags: c#, codedom, pex

I am using CodeDom to generate a class which include some methods. I was able to declare an attribute for my methods to look similar as what Pex does when it creates a parameterized unit test:

```
[PexMethod]
public void myMethod()
```

However I would like to include something more to it like:

```
[PexMethod (Max Branches = 1000)]
public void myMethod()
```

But I am not able to include the `((Max Branches = 1000))`. Could you somebody help me a bit?

Comment: how to add [TestFixture] to a method using codedom

Answer (score 2):

You can't have spaces in the attribute values, they are just wrappers around public properties in your custom attributes class.  For example:

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use this like this

```
[TestAttribute(Enabled = true)]
void Foo(){}
```

So since the attribute maps to a property it has to follow normal syntactical naming rules.

Comment: My bad, in fact the attribute should be without spaces [PexMethod(MaxBranches=1000)], but even so, how you do it with codeDom?

Comment: Sorry Peter, can't help ya there. I've never used codeDom, but if the attribute values have a public setter and it inherits from the attribute class you should be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but you can simply set [the `Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeattributeargument.value.aspx) on [`CodeAttributeArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeattributeargument.aspx):

```
var method =
    new CodeMemberMethod
    {
        Name = "MyMethod",
        CustomAttributes =
        {
            new CodeAttributeDeclaration
            {
                Name = "PexMethod",
                Arguments =
                {
                    new CodeAttributeArgument
                    {
                        Name = "MaxBranches",
                        Value = new CodePrimitiveExpression(1000)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I know this is a long shot, seeing as this thread is 2 years old, but how do I create arguments with enum values?

     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "MyTemplate", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
           

I've managed to do the strings, but I don't know what to do about the enums - RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json and ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

Comment: Also, how would I go about creating this [FaultContract(typeof(Collection<Fout>))]

Comment: @Shaggydog You should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

The [MaxBranches](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/MaxBranches.html) property is on a base class ([PexSettingsAttributeBase](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/PexSettingsAttributeBase.html)).  That may be why you are having trouble.  You may be reflecting over the wrong type to find the PropertyInfo to set.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CodeAttributeArgument codeAttr = new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("Max Branches = 1000"));
     CodeAttributeDeclaration codeAttrDecl = new CodeAttributeDeclaration("PexMethod",codeAttr);

 mymethod.CustomAttributes.Add(codeAttrDecl);
```